# Powerpoint margins when using a projector

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, projector, margins

I'm creating a Powerpoint presentation and I'm having trouble fitting everything (graphics) onto a slide.  I've been trying to stay within the margins provided by the default template.

I'm not sure if these are "margins" per se though-- do they have any real significance or is it just aesthetics? I would like to have my images extend to the very edges of the slide, but I'm worried that parts will get cut off when I put it up on a projector.

Can I safely put stuff outside these margins or it get cut off on a projector?

Answer (score 0):

There's a gray area outside the slide itself; anything out there will be cropped off.  Anything on the slide will appear on screen in slide show view and generally anything that appears on your computer screen *should* also appear on the projector.  Of course, if the projector's set up to toss an image slightly bigger than the screen or if the screen is draped, stuff could be cut off there.  It's always a good idea to avoid slamming anything important right up to the edges of your slide.

If you NEED to do that in order to get all of your text onto the slide, you're trying to put too much on a slide and maybe need to rethink things. ;-)